# Simple web scraping with puppeteer / cheerio not working with params

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to scrape https://www.premierleague.com/clubs/38/Wolverhampton-Wanderers/stats?se=274 
The results being returned are for the page minus the ?se=274
This is applied by using the filter dropdown on the page and selecting 2019/20 season. I can navigate directly to the page and it works fine, but through code it does not work.

I have tried in cheerio and puppeteer. I was going to try nightmare too but this seems overkill I think. I am clearly not an expert! ;)

```
function getStats(callback){
    var url = "https://www.premierleague.com/clubs/38/Wolverhampton-Wanderers/stats?se=274";

    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
        //console.log(html);

        var $ = cheerio.load(html); 

        if(!error){
            $('.allStatContainer.statontarget_scoring_att').filter(function(){
                var data = $(this);
                var vSOT = data.text();

                //console.log(data);
                console.log(vSOT);

            });
        }
    });
    callback;
}
```

This will return 564 instead of 2

Comment: That number is coming from a XHR so cheerio won't show it. Puppeteer will but you might need a delay.

Comment: Hi, I have been trying puppeteer but not having much luck. Not sure how to apply the delay. Any examples?

Comment: I believe you just do: `await page.waitFor(1000)` where 1000 is 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're calling `callback` before `request` returns. Move the callback call into the internal block, where the task you need is completed (in your case, it looks like the `filter` block).

It also looks like you're missing the `()` on the callback call.

Also, a recommendation: return the value you need through the callback.

Comment: Hi TTG, thanks for such a quick response. Looks like "callback;" is correct, "callback();" gives an error - "callback is not a function". I have moved callback like you said but still the same answer.

Comment: It all depends on how you call `getStats`. You need to send a callback function as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Hi, no it's not that. This is dynamic content, I think the point is you need to use something like phantom or nightmare to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So this code works....$10 from a rent-a-coder did the trick. Easy when you know how!

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()

    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto('https://www.premierleague.com/clubs/4/Chelsea/stats?se=274')

    const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

    await sleep(4000)

    const element = await page.$(".allStatContainer.statontarget_scoring_att");
    const text = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element);

    console.log("Shots on Target:"+text)

    browser.close()

})()
```

Comment: Starts at "const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');" and the trailing () are required...no idea why. Does anyone know?

Comment: This is added to make use of async-await (since it can only be used in an async function